# Incremented Page in ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have an .asp page (index.asp) with a previous and next button in the footer.

```
<a class="btn" href="#" target="iframe"> <i class="icon-chevron-left"></i> Back </a><a class="btn" href="#" target="iframe"> Next <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

In between the header and the footer is an iframe with an id of "iframe".

I have 35 pages that need to be displayed in sequence within the iframe starting with 01.asp

I need to be able to keep count of which page is currently being displayed, with the next button going to the next page in  the sequence, but ending at the page 35.asp. The previous button cannot go back previous to 01.asp.

I tried something like this in the 01.asp file:

```
<% curPg=1%> 
<% nxtPg = curPg + 1%>
<% prvPg = curPg - 1%>
<% prvPgURL = prvPg&".asp" %>
<% nxtPgURL = nxtPg&".asp" %>
```

and then added this to the button  tag: <% nxtPgURL %>

```
<a class="btn" href="<% nxtPgURL %>" target="iframe"> Next <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> </a>
```

The variables are declared in the the index.asp file

My asp is very weak, and I need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%%>` is simply a code block (meaning code that runs in the server side).

If you want to *output* something, you need to use `<% Response.Write("some output here")%>`, or the equivalent shortcut - `<%="some output here"%>`.

In your last example, this would look like:

```
<a class="btn" href="<%= nxtPgURL %>" target="iframe"> Next <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i> </a>
```

Note the `=` just after the opening `<%`.

Comment: Ok, that works, but how do I increment the curPg (current page) variable with each next button click, or decrement it with each back button click, and at the same update the href value for so the urls change?

ie: if i am on page 05.asp, the next button should point to page 06.asp, and the back button to page 04.asp

Comment: @livi1717 - No idea. I don't really understand how you have structured your site and how you are passing the page numbers between pages (and anyhow, it's going beyond the scope of your original question - you can always ask another question).